Bolt 2017 Premier leather seats - PU leather or PVC leather or what?
I've read the leather seats have actual leather on the center of the seats where there are perforations (or at least that area is made of particles of real leather bound together with vinyl) and the rest is leatherette, whatever that means. Is the fake leather made of PU or PVC? Looked around in manual and online but couldn't find that materials info, does anyone know?
I ask since PVC is notably worse for offgassing and decomposing, compared with PU.

I can't answer your question directly about a 2017 Bolt, but I want to give you more info that won't fit in a comment.
Leatherette / pleather / fake leather can be either PU or PVC depending on what the manufacturer provides.
Fake leather can be identified by finding a hidden area and touching it with a red hot piece of wire or a soldering iron. You could also cut off a tiny piece from a hidden edge, hold it with tweezers and burn it in a flame. Real leather chars and smells like burning hair. Fake leather melts and smells like plastic.
You can also do a sniff test without taking a sample. Fake leather smells like plastic, real leather smells like leather.
There is yet another type of leather called "double cast" leather. It starts with real leather of low quality that is skived (thinned) by machinery, then coated with PU on the front surface only. It is more durable and less prone to degrading than fake leather, but not as long lasting as real leather. If you can expose the back of it, you'll see real leather, but the front has an artificial appearance such as a regular pattern under a magnifier.
